# Python: Create new files with two parts incrementing names based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, increment

I am pretty new to Python, and currently working on a script to help me automate the task of creating multiple files with a similar file-name structure and I couldn't seem to get it working.

I would like to create a function that takes in a user input(), for example, the letter "T" and how many "T" would user like to make, and it automatically creates a bundle of files with the format as follows:

- T1_S1.txt
- T1_S2.txt
- T1_S3.txt
- T1_S4.txt
- T2_S1.txt
- T2_S2.txt
- T2_S3.txt
- T2_S4.txt
- .....

So for each "T", there should be four "S" before the increment of the "T" part adds a new increment number.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple answer and you can customize it too.

```
def CreateFile(filerange, filename, extension_name, extension_length):
    for i in range(0, filerange):
        for j in range(0, extension_length):
            f = open(f"{filename}{i+1}_{extension_name}{j+1}.txt", "a")
            f.write("You can add here your text or customize as per your needs")
            f.close()


CreateFile(2, 'T', 'S', 4)
```

Hope This help you:

```
filerange -> no of files you need eg:2 files T1,T2
filename  -> Should be your filename eg:T
extension_name -> eg:S
extension_length -> eg:S1,S2,S3,S4
```

Here is the output:

```
T1_S1.txt
T1_S2.txt
T1_S3.txt
T1_S4.txt
T2_S1.txt
T2_S2.txt
T2_S3.txt
T2_S4.txt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this works perfectly for what I am intending to do :D

Comment: @Toboggan Happy to see that my answer work for you. Please close the question by clicking the tick button and upvoting so that question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create files using the built-in with function, and you can loop through a function that would create a variety of files with names.
Something like this:[image: your image description goes here]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little bit of arithmetics and write:

```
def fileCreator(num):
    for i in range(num):
        open(f"T{1 + i // 4}_S{1 + i % 4}.txt", "w")
```

The only argument is the number of files you want to create.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a unix system mac/linux then you can simply do this

```sh
touch T{1..2}_S{1..4}.txt
```